# DROP User @ Azure SQL Database, mapped on database scoped credentials

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database

I want to drop a user who has a mapping to a database scoped credential.

When I use the command

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.database_scoped_credentials
```

I see the credentials with the `principal_id` of the user I want to drop.

How can I change the mapping of the `principal_id` to the database scoped credential?

When I use the drop command I get the following error message

> The database principal has granted or denied permissions to objects in the database and cannot be dropped

Answer (score 0):

It could be the user that you are trying to drop has played a role of grantor and hence you need to revoke those accesses before performing drop of user.

Try running below command to get details of grantee first:

```
select                     
 permission_name,                     
 state_desc,                     
 object_name(major_id) as securable,                     
 user_name(grantor_principal_id) as grantor                     
 from sys.database_permissions                     
 where grantee_principal_id = user_id('User Name to be dropped')
```

Next will be to find details on grantor using below:

```
select *                     
from sys.database_permissions                     
where grantor_principal_id = user_id ('User Name to be dropped');
```

On the basis of the result what you get from above query, you need to perform one of below:

```
REVOKE VIEW DEFINITION ON USER::User Name to be dropped TO public                    
REVOKE CONTROL ON USER::User Name to be dropped TO public                    
REVOKE ALTER ON USER::User Name to be dropped TO public    

REVOKE ALTER ON USER::User Name to be dropped TO *grantee*            
REVOKE CONTROL ON USER::User Name to be dropped TO *grantee*            
REVOKE VIEW DEFINITION ON USER::User Name to be dropped TO *grantee*
```

Alongwith this, there could be some other type of access which might have been granted. So, you need to check the same and execute revoke accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The queries have helped. With the help of
`REVOKE CONTROL ON DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAIL`
I was able to reset the permissions for the user.

Unfortunately the mapping is still there. When I execute the query `SELECT * FROM sys.database_scoped_credentials` I still get the same result. The `principal_id` of the user is still entered.